# Python GET requests - 415 unsupported media type

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying use `get` and i'm getting 415 error - unsupported media type:

```
import requests
import json
...
parameters = {
    'ReceiverIdentificationNumber': company_id_receiver
}

header = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
}
response = requests.get(url, params=parameters, headers=header)
print(response.status_code)
```

I'm using other get methods from the same API and it works, but here is a problem.

Comment: Most probably, the response you are getting from the endpoint for this request is not of json type.

Comment: Most probably the server expects you send this as json payload, not url params. Review the API doc.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to the header as well.

You can aslo try with `'Accept': 'application/json','application/xml',` in you header, see if it will maybe return xml.